# Authenticate username and password (Active Directory - Windows)

Tags: node.js, windows, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I need to use windows authentication in an App built using Nodejs (Express) on back-end and Reactjs on Front-end and I found some tools for example:

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sspi
2. https://github.com/auth0/passport-windowsauth
3. https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory
4. https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-ldapauth
5. https://www.npmjs.com/package/LDAP

I would like to know what is the better tool to use since I have to have a login page and validate the user and password to see if the user has access to a directory.

If the user is not under a certain group want not to allow them to access the application.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.